# Access private variables of a class in other project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, oop, project

I have a huge Objective-C project which I want to split into several ones in a single WorkSpace. Initially I did it, and code compiled well, but I decided also to move one category of a big class to other project, and now linker doesn't understand the situation:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_MyClass.data", referenced from:
      -[MyClass(Viz) someTask] in MyClass+Viz.o

d: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64  
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Briefly, my workspace looks like this:

```
- MyLib project:
    MyClass.h
    MyClass.m
    MyClass+Inner.h
    MyClass+Inner.m

- MyApp project:
    MyClass+Viz.h
    MyClass+Viz.m
```

MyLib is compiled into `MyLib.framework` which is used in MyApp. As I said, before moving `MyClass+Viz` to MyApp project, all the complex logic worked correctly, so there is probably no problem with projects linking. Also, I checked twice that all the files are marked correctly in **Build Phases** settings section.

This is the `MyClass.h` file:

```c
@interface MyClass : NSObject
- (instancetype)init;
- (void)public_methods;
@end
```

This is the `MyClass+Inner.h` file:

```c
#import "MyClass.h"

@interface MyClass ()
{
    // Variables placed here
    // so that only class methods can access them
    SomeStruct* data;
    // other fields ...
}
@end

@interface MyClass (Inner)
- (void)private_methods;
@end
```

And the `MyClass+Viz.m` file:

```c
#import "MyClass+Viz.h"
#import "MyClass+Inner.h"

@implementation MyClass (Viz)
 - (int)someTask {
    return data->length;
    // this or any other stuff with
    // class variables from MyClass+Inner.h
    // leads to "Undefined symbols" by linker
}
@end
```

How can I make it work, make linker see class' private variables from other project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should be using `@property` and not instance variables, generally.

Secondly, you would do something like this using multiple header files and class extensions.

Typcially,

MyClass.h
MyClass_Internal.h
MyClass.m
MyClass_Internal.m (Not typically used)

MyClass.m would import both headers.   MyClass.h would define the public interface and MyClass_Internal.h would have a class extension to provide the private interface:

```
@interface MyClass()
@property(...) Thing *internalThing;
@end
```

Comment: 1. Yes, I just checked properties, they work well. But could you please tell me, why variables aren't accessible from a category if it is implemented in other project?
2. I think I already use multiple header files and class extensions  though it is called categories.

Comment: @AivanF. Categories and class extensions are two different things.   They serve different purposes.